# Problema con concat, valor de variable y prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statements

Estoy escribiendo un procedimiento que formatea texto en formato JSON (uso MySQL 5.6.51 y no tengo la posibilidad de actualizar).
He conseguido lograr la consulta que me devuelve el texto formateado y la ejecuto con un `prepared statement`. Sin embargo, desconozco la cantidad de campos que tendrá la consulta. La línea que me está dando dolores de cabeza es:

```
set consulta_parcial = concat(consulta_parcial, '''"', campo_parcial, '":"', campo_parcial, '"''');
```

La consulta resultante, que es "correcta",  previa a la ejecución es:

```
select concat('[', group_concat('{', '"nombre":"nombre"', ',', '"cantidad":"cantidad"', '}'), ']') as resultado_json from herramientas where id = 1;
```

Y el resultado es:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| resultado_json                              |
+---------------------------------------------+
| [{"nombre":"nombre","cantidad":"cantidad"}] |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,04 sec)
```

Pero el valor no lo está tomando de la tabla y no sé cómo conseguirlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Las columnas deben quedar por fuera de la concatenación, para que te de los valores de esas columnas. Como lo tienes ahora estás concatenando una cadena sin más.

Así debería funcionar:

```
select 
    concat(
            '[', 
            group_concat(
              '{', 
              '"nombre":"',
              nombre,
              '"', 
              ',', 
              '"cantidad":"',
              cantidad,
              '"', 
              '}'), 
        ']') as resultado_json 
from herramientas 
    where id = 1;
```

Observa que `nombre` y `cantidad` están por fuera en la parte derecha del eventual JSON, sin comillas dobles, así serán reconocidas como columnas en la instrucción SQL. Las comillas dobles de pondrán, la primera después de los dos puntos del nombre de la propiedad y la segunda, después del valor en sí mismo, que será tomado de la columna.

Aquí te dejo un fiddle completo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE herramientas (
  id INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(250),
  cantidad INT
);
INSERT INTO herramientas (id,nombre,cantidad) VALUES (1,'Martillo',5);
INSERT INTO herramientas (id,nombre,cantidad) VALUES (1,'Alicate',7);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select 
    concat(
            '[', 
            group_concat(
              '{', 
              '"nombre":"',
              nombre,
              '"', 
              ',', 
              '"cantidad":"',
              cantidad,
              '"', 
              '}'), 
            ']'
    ) as resultado_json 
from herramientas 
    where id = 1;
```

| resultado_json |
| --- |
| [{"nombre":"Martillo","cantidad":"5"},{"nombre":"Alicate","cantidad":"7"}] |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tYn1x62BKBfuvCnWCDPSY3/0)

Comment: Claro, entiendo eso. Solo que en este caso, no conozco de antemano cuáles serán las columnas ni qué cantidad de columnas se solicitarán ni de qué tabla. Tomo los campos del `select`, con `substring_index` los separo, y a partir de ahí empiezo a concatenar la consulta final. Así como me puede venir `select nombre, cantidad from herramientas` me puede venir `select campo, otro_campo from otra_tabla`.

Comment: La variable `campo_parcial` es a la vez nombre de propiedad y referencia al campo de la tabla

Comment: @julio no puedes usar nombres de columnas o de tablas como comodines en las consultas preparadas. Otra cosa, ¿de dónde sale el `group_concat` en tu consulta resultante?

Comment: Ese `group_concat` está justo afuera del `while` que contiene `set consulta_parcial` (únicamente). Como decía, no sé de antemano què campos ni sobre qué tabla será la consulta.